# How will i create batch file like Zend_tool or symfony.bin?

Tags: php, frameworks, batch-file

I want to write batch file for my own php framework. for example i will use it to create controller or modul .If you have already used Zend or symfony you may know how to use .bin file of framework. I only know coding with php so i need clear description of how to write batch file .I looked symfony.bin's source code but code is very simple i think there is a something which send commands to php files and returns response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only know PHP, then do the setup script in it as well. PHP has excellent support for writing [CLI applications](https://www.php.net/CLI) (Command Line Interface). This also gives you several advantages over a shell script solution, such as access to reflection classes, which you could use to automatically extract the structure of abstract classes and interfaces and generate code templates.

Comment: but i have to use it where does not have php support.